# Is there a way in a GitHub Pages website to store the contents of a textbox between sessions?

Tags: javascript, html

What I am trying to do is when someone navigates to my website, it will ask their name or simply have a generic and say "Not you, click here". Afterwards, in the corner it will display "Welcome back, [name]." However, this is a GitHub Pages website so I am not certain if this is possible, and it would have to simply leave out the name.

It does work to simply hardcode a name or have none at all, but without some sort of database or ability to store and retrieve credentials I don't know how I can achieve this.

All I have currently in the webpage is

`<p style="text-align:right; color:gray"><i>Welcome back.</i></p>.`

I was unable to find something similar to my question on Google, I'm not certain on how to word it besides keywords that don't quite get me where I'm going.

I don't believe that the website can write to the user's system without some sort of cookies, but I do not know much about storing data with them. I'm guessing I will need to take advantage of the HTML5 `window.LocalStorage` but I am not sure how to implement it.

Essentially, is there a way to store someone's name in cookies, website cache, or somewhere not on the server end, as from what I can tell GitHub Pages is read-only.

Comment: Nope, you can't do that. GitHub pages also isn't exactly the right platform to host stuff like that. To store information between sessions, you will need to leverage on a server-side solution. You can of course store the info in localStorage, but the user can clear it at his/her own discretion.

Comment: Sound like `Localstrage`

Comment: Right. I was thinking of somehow checking the contents of localStorage, and if it's empty, to prompt the user or simply show nothing until it's filled. It shouldn't be permanent and unchangeable later on.

Comment: if you can run js you can use local storage

Comment: LocalStorage can solve what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, localstorage (or a cookie) is about the only way to do what you want without your own server or some external service.

This is by no means a permanent storage solution and you have no control over how the user manages their local storage, but here is a minimal example you could throw into an HTML file and open in your browser to test out.

```
<input id="local-input" onkeydown="store(this)">

<script>
    // keep the contents of the input in local storage, called by input onkeydown
    function store(e) {
        localStorage.setItem('local', e.value)
    }

    // if previous storage exists, use it
    if(localStorage.getItem('local') !== null) {
        document.getElementById('local-input').value = localStorage.getItem('local')
    }
</script>
```

Local storage is quite easy to use. Refer to online documentation for more examples and guidance: [MDN Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Okay. I'm attempting to get this to work with placing ```<script>localStorage.getItem('local')</script>``` where a name would be written normally. However it simply remains blank. Where does this go wrong? I have placed the code written above in a page to test this.

Comment: After some more work I've gotten it to work after a page refresh on my local system by adding a ```<span id="typedname"></span>``` in the ```Welcome back, [name].``` area where ```[name]``` would be. I did this by appending ```<script> document.getElementById("typedname").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('local'); </script> ```which seems to work.